# Importing a picture and being able to shrink/expand with another click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a macro to import a picture in an excel sheet, but I want the picture to be small compressed. After import I want to be able to click on the picture to expand, and click again to shrink. I've found the following two macros but I'm novice at VBA and am having trouble combining them. Thanks in advance

```
Sub CompressPicture()
Dim fName As String
Dim pic As Picture
Dim r As Range

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Images (*.jpg;*.gif;*.png),*.jpg;*.gif;*.png", _
        Title:="Please select an image...")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set r = ActiveCell
Set pic = Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Insert(fName)

With pic
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Left = r.Left
    .Top = r.Top
    .Width = r.Width
    .Height = r.Height
    .Select
End With

If TypeName(Selection) = "Picture" Then
    Application.SendKeys "%a~"
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
End If
End Sub

Sub Picture2_Click()
Dim shp As Shape
    Dim big As Single, small As Single
    Dim shpDouH As Double, shpDouOriH As Double
    big = 5
    small = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With shp
        shpDouH = .Height
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        shpDouOriH = .Height

        If Round(shpDouH / shpDouOriH, 2) = big Then
            .ScaleHeight small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
        Else
            .ScaleHeight big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoBringToFront
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.

Import several images in a single folder into cells in Excel.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\Briefcase\Digital Pics\8th Wedding Anniversary\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1
For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
            i = i + 1
        fName = Dir
    Loop
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now, increase and decrease your image size like this.

```
Sub IncreaseSize()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim big As Single, small As Single
Dim shpDouH As Double, shpDouOriH As Double
big = 3
small = 1
On Error Resume Next
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
With shp
    shpDouH = .Height
    .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    shpDouOriH = .Height

    If Round(shpDouH / shpDouOriH, 2) = big Then
        .ScaleHeight small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleWidth small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    Else
        .ScaleHeight big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleWidth big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ZOrder msoBringToFront
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Both macros should be assigned to events.  Check out the link below to see how to do this.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4380-excel-click-to-enlarge-image.html